# Slim php session cookie not working

Tags: php, html, cookies, slim

This is the code which i use :

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
'cookies.encrypt' => true,
'cookies.secret_key' => 'secret',
'cookies.cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie(array(
'expires' => '20 minutes',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => null,
'secure' => false,
'httponly' => false,
'name' => 'session_cooki',
'secret' => 'secret',
'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
'cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)));
```

This  is how i intialise variable :

```
$_SESSION['customer_email'] = $result['Email'];
$_SESSION['customer_key'] = $result['Cust_Key'];
```

The **same sets cookie in Windows XAMPP setup**, but **fails to set cookie in Ubuntu Apache2 PHP 5.5.**

Any particular reasons?

Comment: Do you have the crypto module installed in your ubuntu server? php-mcrypt

Comment: Yes. Its installed.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to http://localhost/ then this will not work as cookies are designed for second level domains and down.

Try mapping a hostname with TLD to your 127.0.0.1 address in your hosts file.

Comment: Actually this works only on http://localhost/ . never on production server.